# Error well opening file: exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

Tags: android, cordova, fileopener2

I try to achieve the following behaviour:

- Download file from an external location
- Save it locally
- Open it

The file-opener plugin seemed to be the perfect match, I used an example from (Opening a remote file): https://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/file-opener

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer()
    fileTransfer.download(
     // download from an example pdf
     encodeURI('http://rp.delaat.net/2014-2015/p75/report.pdf'),
     // save to
     'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/test.pdf',
     // open the downloaded file
     function (entry) {
      var file = entry.toURL()
      window.cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
       file,
       'application/pdf',
       {
         error: function (errorMessage) { console.log(errorMessage) },
         success: function () { console.log('succeed') }
       }
    )
  }
)
```

However on android I get the following error:

```
file:///data/user/0/nl.mytestapp/files/files/Download/test.pdf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

I am using cordova, to deploy my app.

Searching for a solution left me empty handed.

**Edit**

The error seems to be in opening the file (fileOpener2), only downloading the file goes fine.

Comment: Which Android version do you have? I can open files on 7.x and 8.0 but I am getting errors on version 8.1. Of course also using this plugin.

Comment: @JornTheunissen Ye I after reinstalling the plugin it worked :)